# Can't recover my .db files

Tags: sms, backup, recovery-mode, sqlite

I did a backup before reseting my phone. I've got two .db files (contacts & text messages); I really want to put them back into my phone but when I try to open them it says "unable to open".

How can I recover them?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We're excited to have you here, but you'll need to give us more information. What method did you use to create these backups?

Comment: I was doing the reset from the phone itself, and it advised me to backup first, which I did. I've got some .db files then, but I dont understand how to put them back on. 

Thanks for edited my headline ;-)